# How to check file system in which Volume Group & Also the Volume Group Detailed information in Linux

Tags: linux, shell-script, volume

I need to know:

1. The File system in Which Volume Group ?
2. The Volume group having how many space ?

Comment: Read a tutorial on the basics of the Linux filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are looking for with question 1. A volume group, in itself, is not really related to file systems. Do you mean which devices are used in the volume group? In this case you can see what volume group a physical volume resides using 'pvdisplay'.

You can view the free space of a volume group with 'vgdisplay'.